Why does my Unity Raycast (for player weapon) pass straight through enemy colliders sometimes, and hit them correctly at other times?
I'm working on an FPS game in Unity 2021.3.13f1. The issue I'm having is quite simple, sometimes when the player shoots, the Raycast will just go straight through the enemy collider whereas other times it doesn't. Here is an example of the issue:

The red lines represent when the raycast does not hit the enemy, but as you can see the ray passes through the enemy collider. In fact, several raycasts pass straight through the enemy collider. It's not a consistent issue either as you can see with the green raycasts in the bottom that represent successful hits that actually damaged the enemy. I have no clue what is causing this issue and it's also quite difficult to replicate.
Initially, I thought this issue could be something to do with the invisible walls that prevent the player from being able to jump over the fences, so I added those to the IgnoreRaycast layer. Furthermore, I've also noticed this issue occur with direct line-of-sight to the enemy with no possible obstacles in between.
Here is my project's GitHub for reference: GH Repo
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Here is the raycast script that I'm using. It's pretty straigthforward and there's no filters or anything that could be causing this:
private void ShootRay() {
    Vector3 fireDirection = CalculateRecoil();
    fireRayCast = new Ray(transform.position, fireDirection);
    RaycastHit hitData;
    if (Physics.Raycast(fireRayCast, out hitData)) {
        Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, hitData.point, Color.red);
        EnemyContainer hitContainer;
        if (hitData.collider.transform.parent.CompareTag("Enemy") && hitData.collider.gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject.TryGetComponent<EnemyContainer>(out hitContainer)) {
            Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, hitData.point, Color.green, 10, false);
            hitContainer.health -= currentWeaponProperties.damage;
            if (hitContainer.health <= 0) {
                playerPoints.AddPoints(hitContainer.points);
                Destroy(hitContainer.gameObject);
            }
        }
    }
    currentRecoil = Mathf.Clamp(currentRecoil + currentWeaponProperties.recoilMod, 0f, 1f);
    Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, fireDirection * 50, Color.red, 10f);
}

All the cast does it check for the enemy tag on the hit but that is only after the hit occurs, which is not happening right now.

raycasts are like 0.000000000000001mm thick.. so it becomes down to tiny tiny fractions it can miss things by (and without looking at your github as frankly thats not how this site works and im not play pick the file)

That’s the thing though, the ray case is passing straight through the center of the enemy collider, so even despite the size it should be a bit. Here is the weapon script (https://github.com/Zurvivors-Org/Zurvivor/blob/main/Assets/Scripts/Player%20Scripts/PlayerWeapon.cs)

that's a 404 error page ... please include a [mcve]

As derHugo says you need to post enough code here that covers all potential questions.  Now, i had something similar when i had a wall, sounds bizarre and i never actually found the true answer but imagine the brick wall, while it was a solid cube with a wall texture, when the raycast went through what would be the mortar of the wall, it would see the enemy behind the wall, and not when there was a brick.. defying blatent logic.  I ended up doing some box casts so it covered a bit more area to tag something and all was good

@derHugo I've updated the post with the relevant code and information

in general I would not use the same ray color for a hit as for a miss - you are overruling with the second DrawRay call so you currently won't see whether the ray hit something or not directly ... your final DrawRay will always overlay the previous line drawings .. you should wrap that in an else and only do it if the raycast didn't hit anything
